# MAC Security - MAC verification queries

Tags: mac, attack, advantage, game

In the applied cryptography book by Boneh and Shoup, Chapter 6 on MACs, it is stated that an adversary that is also capable of requesting the challenger for verification queries (in addition to signing queries) is not stronger than an Adversary that can only ask for signing queries. I do not understand why a verification query cannot be emulated by the signing query Adversary by generating the pair (mi, ti) for himself, and then generate a signing query for the challenger with mi, getting back ti', compare ti'==ti if comparison succeeds, adversary wins, else it fails. Why do you need additional entity (B) between the Adversary to the Challenger?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking; Boneh and Shoup state that adding a verification oracle makes the adversary no stronger; you give some reasoning why adding a verification oracle makes the adversary no stronger (BTW: your reasoning does assume that the MAC is deterministic, as well as the (mi, ti) pair being queried in your process wouldn't count as a forgery).  Since you appear to be agreeing with Boneh and Shoup, what's your question?

Comment: I wonder why it is needed to introduce an additional entity (B) between the Adversary (A) to the challenger in order to prove that the capability of verification queries does not make the Adversary stronger